# value not removed from list when i uncheck a checkbox

Tags: jquery, checkbox

When i uncheck the checkbox the appended value isn't removed from the list

```
var checkarr = [];  
var getdata =[];  

$("input[type=checkbox]").on( "click", function() {  
var pushdata = $(this).val();  
var atLeastOneIsChecked = $('#filter :checkbox:checked').length > 0;   
if (atLeastOneIsChecked )   
{
    checkarr.push(pushdata);
    $('.data').addClass(pushdata);

} 
else   
{
    var getval = $.inArray( pushdata, checkarr );  
    delete checkarr[getval];
    $('.data').removeClass(pushdata);
}


var passval =  $.unique(checkarr);


    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "check.php",
      data: {filterOpts: passval},
      success: function(records)
        {
        var dataval = JSON.parse(records);
        $.each(dataval,function(k,v) {
        getdata.push(v);
        var finddata = $('.data').append('<tr><td>'+v+'</td></tr>');
                $('.data').show();   
        });  


              }


    });  

 });
```

Comment: Set up a demo in JSFiddle so we can see the problem.

Comment: my code is working but i have issue when i uncheck the checkbox append value dont removed  while uncheck checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding and removing data from a list, create the list each time using [.map()](http://api.jquery.com/map/)

Instead of using addClass and removeClass, use [.toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/).

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").on( "change", function() {  

    //var atLeastOneIsChecked = $('#filter :checkbox:checked').length > 0;   
    //if (atLeastOneIsChecked )   
    //{
    //    checkarr.push(pushdata);
    //    $('.data').addClass(pushdata);
    //} 
    //else   
    //{
    //    var getval = $.inArray( pushdata, checkarr );  
    //    delete checkarr[getval];
    //    $('.data').removeClass(pushdata);
    //}

    checkarr = $('#filter :checkbox:checked').map(function(){
        return $(this).val();  
    }).get();

    var pushdata = $(this).val();
    $('.data').toggleClass(pushdata, $(this).is(':checked'));

    var passval =  $.unique(checkarr);
    // etc..

});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/949ogcqx/3/)**

RE the phantom second part to the question, given that I'm having to guess the expected result, I can only suggest that you may want to empty `.data` first..?

```
$('.data').empty().show();   
$.each(dataval,function(k,v) {
    $('.data').append('<tr><td>'+v+'</td></tr>');
});
```

Comment: I have no idea what your intention is with that bit of code. You haven't explained, or shown what is returned in `records`, or made any reference to it in the question.

Comment: $.each(dataval,function(k,v) {
        getdata.push(v);
        var finddata = $('.data').append('<tr><td>'+v+'</td></tr>');
                $('.data').show();   
        });                                                                                                   check these line if response give me a data when i append data in a table . my question is that if i uncheck the checkbox i want to remove these append data if checkbox is cheked then show this data.

Comment: I don't know what data is returned. I am not going to guess. Explain it in the question.

Comment: data is in this format . Samsung Galaxy S 1
Samsung Galaxy S 2
Samsung Galaxy S 3
Samsung Galaxy S 4
Samsung Galaxy S 4 mini

Comment: Please edit your question, adding the second part to it. The answer may be a simple one, but it will make no sense to others if an extra bit is there without it being referred to in the question, and I don't know what the expected result is.

Answer (score 0):

I guess `Array.splice()` can be used to delete a specific item in the array:

```
// delete checkarr[getval];
checkarr.splice(getval, 1); // removes one value at the index of getval.
```

```js
var arr = ['white', 'black', 'red', 'green', 'blue'];
var getval = 2; // this is the index we have supposed.

document.querySelector('span').textContent = 'before splice::::'+JSON.stringify(arr);

arr.splice(getval, 1);

document.querySelector('strong').textContent = 'after splice::::'+JSON.stringify(arr);
```

```html
<span></span>
<br/>
<strong></strong>
```